# Why groovy shows warning "An illegal reflective access operation has occurred" when I use JDK11

Tags: java, groovy

When I use JDK11, and then installed Groovy, some warning occurred like below:

`WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1 (file:/D:/Groovy/groovy-2.5.7/lib/groovy-2.5.7.jar) to constructor java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup(java.lang.Class,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v7.Java7$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Groovy Version: 2.5.7 JVM: 11.0.3 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Windows 10`

When I use JDK 8, there is no warning, anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please see this quote from the JDK11 Release notes:

> **hotspot/runtime ➜ JEP 181 Nest-Based Access Control**
>
> Introduce nests, an access-control context that aligns with the
>   existing notion of nested types in the Java programming language
>   (JEP-181: Nest-based access control).
>
> In Java SE 11, the Java Virtual Machine supports the arrangement of
>   classes and interfaces into a new access control context, called a
>   nest. Nests allow classes and interfaces that are logically part of
>   the same code entity, but which are compiled to distinct class files,
>   to access each other's private members without the need for compilers
>   to insert accessibility-broadening bridge methods. Nests are a
>   low-level mechanism of the Java SE Platform; there are no changes to
>   the access control rules of the Java programming language. The javac
>   compiler has been updated to use nests when compiling nested classes
>   and interfaces in Java source code, by generating new class files
>   attributes that place a top-level class (or interface) and all its
>   nested classes and interfaces in the same nest. The Java Virtual
>   Machine has been updated to use these attributes when checking the
>   accessibility of a private constructor, method, or field, including
>   via core reflection and the java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup API.
>   Membership in a nest is exposed through the new getNestHost and
>   getNestMembers methods of java.lang.Class.
>
> As nest membership is recorded in the class file of the top-level
>   class or interface (the nest host), that class file must be present at
>   run time to allow the access control checks to be performed. This is
>   not normally a concern as the top-level class or interface is
>   typically used directly. In some code where a top-level class or
>   interface acts only as a holder for nested classes or interfaces, and
>   is otherwise unused, packaging tools may have elided that class file
>   from the distribution of a library or application. With nest-based
>   access control, it is no longer possible to elide the top-level class
>   or interface if any of the nested classes or interfaces require access
>   to each other's private members — a NoClassDefFoundError or
>   ClassNotFoundException will be thrown.
>   [Source](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/11-relnote-issues-5012449.html)

So java changed the rules for how access control is established at runtime, and as a result, Groovy, which appears to be a language that leverages the java platform and its libraries, cannot use reflection to access private members.

Oracle expected this kind of issue with this change, and put in an error message, asking you to report the problem to the makers of the offending plugin.

Comment: comon guys, I trawled through release notes here. gotta be worth one point, right? ;-)

Comment: Sometimes it takes years for your contributions to be recognized, but I appreciate your answer. :-)